# See exact time a usb device was removed Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, usb

A little background, I am trying to calibrate a USB accelerometer which starts its timing the moment it is removed from the usb drive, I suspect the timing is a bit off, which leads me to my problem...

Is there any way of seeing the exact time a device was removed?

I could do with the time in milliseconds, is this somehting that could be solved programatically using c#, or is there a log somewhere in windows 7? I am open to any solution.

Comment: There is a *lot* of code that runs when you remove a USB device.  Don't count on getting a time accurate to less than hundreds of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple C# app and subscribe to the Win API notifications for device node changes by the system.

The API function [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431%28VS.85%29.aspx) allows you to subscribe your application or service to be notified by Windows when a change occurs to a device (i.e. hot-plug or unplug).

Your C# application will have to call the register method at start-up, and then the application will have to handle the [WM_DEVICECHANGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28VS.85%29.aspx) event inside the application's WndProc. The way to get access to the WndProc will be slightly different depending on whether you choose to write a WPF application or a WinForms application.

The WM_DEVICECHANGED message will have the WParam set to a specific value, depending on whether the device was just plugged in, it's being removed, or it was just completely removed.  In your case you will probably want to use the [DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

You can then have your C# app log the *exact* time the device was removed. Note that the accuracy of the time-stamp will depend on the delay that exists between the device actually being removed and your application receiving and handling the notification. There is no system-level time-stamp available so that will have to do. But it should be accurate to within a *"few"* milliseconds.